# Failed to "rbt post <CHANGENUM>" from Perforce P4V

Tags: perforce, review-board

I'm trying to "rbt post CHANGENUM"(CHANGENUM is the number of pending list) from Perforce P4V in Windows7.
I succeeded to execute this command from command prompt, but I failed to execute from Perforce P4V with the error below.

```
>>> RBTools 0.7.1 alpha 0 (dev)
>>> Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

>>> Running on Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
>>> Home = C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming
>>> Current directory = c:\Users\xxxx\p4vworkspace

>>> Checking for a Subversion repository...
>>> Unable to execute "svn help": skipping SVN
>>> Checking for a Git repository...
>>> Running: git rev-parse --git-dir

>>> Command exited with rc 128: ['git', 'rev-parse', '--git-dir']
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
---
>>> Checking for a Mercurial repository...

>>> Unable to execute "hg --help": skipping Mercurial
>>> Checking for a CVS repository...
>>> Unable to execute "cvs": skipping CVS
>>> Checking for a Perforce repository...
>>> Running: p4 info

>>> Running: diff --version

>>> repository info: Path: perforce.tw.trendnet.org:1666, Base path: None, Supports changesets: True
>>> Making HTTP GET request to http://xxxxx/api/

Path 'CHANGENUM' does not match a valid Perforce path.
```

CustomTool settings are below

■ Application:C:\Program Files\RBTools\bin\rbt.cmd

■ Arguments: post -d %p

Do you have any ideas to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I unset P4CHARSET before executing rbt post and succeeded to post it